# Blender scripting resize after proportional translation

Tags: python, resize, blender

Working on Blender with python and I am currently trying to proportionally translate two vertices of a circle and then resize the object to its original boundings and center. First i select the vertices I want and I do a proportional translate like so:

```
    bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.use_proportional_edit = True
    bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0, smooth, 0), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', constraint_axis=(False, True, False), mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=True, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=2.71427, use_proportional_connected=True, use_proportional_projected=False, release_confirm=True)
    bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.use_proportional_edit = False
    normalize()
```

Then I call my handmade function normalize to resize and recenter my object:

```
def normalize():

    obj = bpy.context.active_object
    minX = 0
    minY = 0
    maxX = 0
    maxY = 0
    for v in obj.data.vertices:

        vx = (obj.matrix_world @ v.co)[0]
        print(str(v.co[0])+" "+str(vx))
        if vx < minX:
            minX = v.co[0]
        if vx > maxX:
            maxX = v.co[0]
        vy = (obj.matrix_world @ v.co)[1]
        print(str(v.co[1])+" "+str(vy))
        if vy < minY:
            minY = v.co[1]
        if vy > maxY:
            maxY = v.co[1]
    scaleX = 2 / (maxX - minX)
    scaleY = 2 / (maxY - minY)

    # print(str(maxX)+" "+str(minX))
    # print(str(maxY)+" "+str(minY))
    # print(str(scaleX)+" "+str(scaleY))
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
    bpy.context.tool_settings.mesh_select_mode = (True, False, False)
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action = 'SELECT')
    bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(scaleX, scaleY, 1), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', constraint_axis=(True, True, False), mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=2.71427, use_proportional_connected=True, use_proportional_projected=False, release_confirm=True)
    maxX = 0
    maxY = 0

    for v in obj.data.vertices:
        vx = (obj.matrix_world @ v.co)[0]
        if vx > maxX:
            maxX = v.co[0]
        vy = (obj.matrix_world @ v.co)[1]
        if vy > maxY:
            maxY = v.co[1]
    dx = 1 - maxX
    dy = 1 - maxY
    bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(dx, dy, 0), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', constraint_axis=(True, True, False), mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=2.71427, use_proportional_connected=True, use_proportional_projected=False, release_confirm=True)
```

But both local and global coordinates of the circle seems that remained untouched, even if I can see for sure, running the script, that the proportional translation has been applied!
Where is the error? HELP

Answer (score 0):

Alright I think I figured it out. The fact is that you always have to switch back to object mode to be sure your transformations have been applied. So I just toggled Object mode and edit mode after each transformation and it worked!